# Wes Baker's "Subscriber" works with Solspace' User?

Tags: solspace

I'm looking for a way to add via Solspace User to a mailchimp list and I found http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/subscriber and not sure if it works. Wes told me he hasn't tried. Any ideas?

Comment: Could give more details on what you're trying to do? Do you simply want to populate Subscriber's name and email fields with a user's data?

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Subscriber with Solspace User, so can't really give a final answer, but keep in mind that User stores EE member data the same way and in the same place as the native EE Member Module does. If subscriber works with the native EE Member Module, then chances are it would work with User as well.

If you're tying to simply display a member's name and email address in the "name" and "email" address of the Subscriber form, then I assume User would work here. In fact, even native EE tools can be used to get a user's name and email if that's the only purpose. :)